# How to use React setState inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I have this `createRoleMember` function that updates a component's state so React can re-render table () inside the component and display the newly added `roleMembers` as rows.

```
  createRoleMember = (newRoleMember) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { roleMembers: prevState.roleMembers.concat([newRoleMember]) };
    });
  };
```

The code works when I add a single member, but if the array contains more than one value, the `createRoleMember` function re-renders the table with the correct amount of new rows but with the same repeated username (always duplicating the last username in the array).

For example, if the array looks like this `["testOne, "testTwo", "testThree"], the table will be re-rendered like this:

```
testthree   xxx Aug 25, 2020    
testthree   xxx Aug 25, 2020    
testthree   xxx Aug 25, 2020
```

Instead of:

```
testtone    xxx Aug 25, 2020    
testttwo    xxx Aug 25, 2020    
testthree   xxx Aug 25, 2020
```

**If I reload the page, the table displays the correct data.**

How can I call `createRoleMember` (which contains `setState`) inside a loop?

**More Context**

The `createRoleMember` function gets called in a loop that looks like this:

```
  aliasArray.forEach((currAlias) => {
    memberAttributes.alias = currAlias;
    const marshalledObj = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall(memberAttributes);

    const params = {
      TableName: "xxxx",
      Item: marshalledObj,
    };

    axios
      .post(
        "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx",
        params
      )
      .then(() => {
        createRoleMember(memberAttributes);
        const newRow = document.getElementById(
          `${memberAttributes.alias}-${memberAttributes.Role}`
        );
        newRow.classList.add("new-row");
      });
  });
```

- `aliasArray`: an array of strings like "username1","username2".
- `memberAttributes`: an object with the member's data, e.g., username, grantedBy, grantedOn.
- `newRow`: allows me to provide feedback to the user (highlights new row in green).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your code here:

```js
aliasArray.forEach((currAlias) => {
    memberAttributes.alias = currAlias; // Here's the problem

    // ...

    axios
      .post(/*...*/)
      .then(() => {
        createRoleMember(memberAttributes);
        // ...
      });
  });
```

Each time the forEach callback is invoked, you're updating the value of `memberAttributes.alias`. So after all the members of `aliasArray` have been iterated, the value of `memberAttributes.alias` is the last value of `aliasArray`.

So when your requests come back and the success callback (`.then(...)`) is executed, `memberAttributes.alias` is going to be that last value of `aliasArray` for each invocation.
I believe your issue would be resolved by propagating `currAlias` through to the success callback like:

```js
aliasArray.forEach((currAlias) => {
    memberAttributes.alias = currAlias;
    const marshalledObj = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.marshall(memberAttributes);

    const params = {
      TableName: "xxxx",
      Item: marshalledObj,
    };

    axios
      .post(
        "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx",
        params
      )
      .then(() => {
        memberAttributes.alias = currAlias;
        createRoleMember(memberAttributes); 
        const newRow = document.getElementById(
          `${currAlias}-${memberAttributes.Role}` // Modified this line
        );
        newRow.classList.add("new-row");
      });
  });


createRoleMember = (newRoleMember) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { roleMembers: prevState.roleMembers.concat([{...newRoleMember}]) };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Why can't I do `memberAttributes.alias = currAlias` right after the `then`? I tried and didn't work and since that doesn't work, why would  `createRoleMember(memberAttributes,currAlias)` work? Strange cause if I `console.log(currAlias)` I do get two logs, with the expected values. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @TheDaniel Good point, you should be able to update `memberAttributes.alias` in the then and save yourself from changing the signature of `createRoleMember`. 

I believe there's a subtle bug here. You're updating `memberAttributes` and then (in `createRoleMember`) you're pushing that onto the state. But you're never re-assigning `memberAttributes`, so each object in the state is actually a reference to the __same object__.

I've updated my answer to include a fix for this issue. Note that I'm now using the object spread operator in createRoleMember to create a new object.